# Never ending read request.! Reentrant Lock

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, reentrantlock

While writing a piece of code for work I have encountered a use case for ReentrantReadWriteLock. So far my understanding is as long as there are more than zero thread with read lock a thread cannot acquire write lock. Application I am working on is read heavy with very less writes. Is it possible that more than zero thread will always have a read lock acquired and if a thread requires a write lock it will forever be suspended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as "writer starvation".

When looking at the Javadoc for [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html), we can find the following paragraphs:

> This class does not impose a reader or writer preference ordering for
> lock access. However, it does support an optional fairness policy.
>
> Non-fair mode (default) When constructed as non-fair (the default),
> the order of entry to the read and write lock is unspecified, subject
> to reentrancy constraints. A nonfair lock that is continuously
> contended may indefinitely postpone one or more reader or writer
> threads, but will normally have higher throughput than a fair lock.
>
> Fair mode When constructed as fair, threads contend for entry using an
> approximately arrival-order policy. When the currently held lock is
> released, either the longest-waiting single writer thread will be
> assigned the write lock, or if there is a group of reader threads
> waiting longer than all waiting writer threads, that group will be
> assigned the read lock.
>
> A thread that tries to acquire a fair read lock (non-reentrantly) will
> block if either the write lock is held, or there is a waiting writer
> thread. The thread will not acquire the read lock until after the
> oldest currently waiting writer thread has acquired and released the
> write lock. Of course, if a waiting writer abandons its wait, leaving
> one or more reader threads as the longest waiters in the queue with
> the write lock free, then those readers will be assigned the read
> lock.
>
> A thread that tries to acquire a fair write lock (non-reentrantly)
> will block unless both the read lock and write lock are free (which
> implies there are no waiting threads). (Note that the non-blocking
> ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock.tryLock() and
> ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock.tryLock() methods do not honor this
> fair setting and will immediately acquire the lock if it is possible,
> regardless of waiting threads.)

In short: If you don't specify that the ReentrantReadWriteLock uses a fair policy, that can happen